# make a script loop and auto search for new value

Tags: javascript

I can't find how to make a script loop, I know I need setTimeout but I don't know how to implement it, the script should run in a loop auto searching for new values!

```js
var time = document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML;
if (time < 0.4) {
    var x2 = document.getElementById("2x-total").innerHTML;
    var x3 = document.getElementById("3x-total").innerHTML;
    if (x2 < 2 * x3) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false,
            false, false, false, 0, null);
        var run = document.getElementById("btn2x");
        run.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}

function x2a() {       
    document.getElementById("x2p").innerHTML = x2;
}

function x3a() {       
    document.getElementById("x3p").innerHTML = x3;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer" >00.14</div> //value is always changing

<button id="btn2x"  onclick="x2a()" style="display: block;">2x</button>
<button id="btn3x"  onclick="x3a()" style="display: block;">3x</button>
<span id="2x-total">12000</span>    //value is also changing
<span id="3x-total">7000</span>    //value is also changing
<p id="x2p"></p>
<p id="x3p"></p>
```

How could I make it loop and also read the new values for "timer" , "2x-total" and "3x-total" with an interval of 50~100 miliseconds!

Comment: Please format this code using (eg. http://jsbeautifier.org/ ) first.

Comment: first thing that i noticed with your code is that you're declaring var x2 and var x3 twice

Comment: any idea how to make it loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use setInterval() method.

put your code like

```
function wrapperFunction() {
    setInterval(function(){ 
      // your code here which will be executed every 100 ms
    }, 100);
}
```

now call this wrapperFunction() one time and then code inside it will execute every 100 ms

Comment: it doesn't work at all , the code doesn't execute , and the script should go in a loop how could I do that?